# Delete repository from local with effect server data?

Tags: repository, tortoisesvn, local

I just want to delete my repository in my local pc because the size is too big. My idea is keep all file in svn server and delete svn on local pc so that all file is backup on server. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Via FTP or Samba you could map a network drive to the repository's location on the server. This would allow you to directly access the files (edit a project in an IDE, etc) and commit directly to the server without any local hard drive space consumed.

Be aware, if you are using your repository for code, compiling will most likely be severely limited by your network connection.